# Trace memory leaks in android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-memory, hprof, eclipse-mat

I'm trying to trace memory leaks in my app. I have an `Activity` in which I can switch between 7 `Fragment`s. I'm instantiating the `Fragment`s in the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` and using the same instances when switching between them.

I'm using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load any images in the `Fragment`s. As I switch between the `Fragment`s, the memory allocation keeps increasing and even on finishing the `Activity`, the memory is not freed.

I've used MAT to analyze the heap dump and it seems it's the `Bitmap`s that aren't being freed.

I understand that I have a leak in the `Activity` that contains the `Fragment`s but since the the memory isn't being freed even after exiting the `Activity`, I guess I'm also holding onto the `Activity` also.

Since I haven't been able to use MAT in a beneficent way to identify the leaks (neither figure out where I'm holding onto the `Activity`), I'd appreciate if someone could help me out.

Comment: do you _recycle()_ the bitmaps?

Comment: hmm lets do this, if you can post the Mat stats or you can post some codes in respect to how you close the activities, how you persist the fragment and whether you hold static bitmaps or static variables  and also are you sure `onDestroy()` is always called on all 7+1 classes? get specific SIr